# Simple Throttle control in Go

Tags: go

How to create a simple throttle control to stop your API receiving to many requests. or effectively getting DDOSed? Since sometimes you might have a forward facing API passing all connections to your service. There is as mentioned some other solutions that build throttle into the actual connection, but do over complicate what is effectively a simple solution, looking at the recommended solutions, they pretty much do what is suggested below by adding id to a map. For those still learning, this is not a bad option, but as go is so great, you can attempt simple, and then refine to a better solution as you begin to understand the mechanisms better.
Though this was flagged as promoting some Book or something, it is simply my attempt to help others. if that's bad, then Ill stay bad. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some simple throttle control code, use this as an IF call with the unique identifier of said service, in this case an IP, and the time you want to wait. as you can see by the code, you can change seconds to minutes or milliseconds. and you would be better to use a service like cloudflare, but as a last stand option, placing this in your API and putting an IF statement around the handler code, you can throttle control the connections. this is to keep it simple, I am sure there are other elegant solutions out their, and my dumb attempt might be ridiculed, but I am sure someone will learn from this, and suggestions for improvement will also be included if they make sense.

```
/******************************************************************************
 *      _   _               _   _   _               _ _
 *     | | | |             | | | | | |        /\   | | |
 *     | |_| |__  _ __ ___ | |_| |_| | ___   /  \  | | | _____      __
 *     | __| '_ \| '__/ _ \| __| __| |/ _ \ / /\ \ | | |/ _ \ \ /\ / /
 *     | |_| | | | | | (_) | |_| |_| |  __// ____ \| | | (_) \ V  V /
 *      \__|_| |_|_|  \___/ \__|\__|_|\___/_/    \_\_|_|\___/ \_/\_/
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This function will temp store the value in a map and then remove it, it will
 * return true or false if the item is in the map, Now sets delay on second response
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
var throttle = make(map[string]bool)
func throttleAllow(ip string, timeout int) (retVal bool) {
    if throttle[ip] == true {
        fmt.Println("WARM","-=Throttle=-To frequent calls from:",ip)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(timeout)*time.Second) //Random next cycle.
        retVal = true  // false will result is receiging to frequent message
    } else {
        throttle[ip] = true
        go func(){
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(timeout)*time.Second) //Random next cycle.
            delete(throttle, ip)
        }()
        retVal = true
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this with the library package `golang.org/x/time/rate` without the need to create so many go routines. There is a blog post here about it https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/how-to-rate-limit-http-requests

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, it is useful, I prefer to not bloat my code with libraries that have additional unused functions and code.  A lot of Developers don't care to much about how large a file is, or how much memory is used, treating it as an infinite resource. But even though my code would really not be an issue, it's just a personal habit from old school. I remember writing code on a Spectrum 48K machine, and a sinclair 81 1K machine. so pardon my approach and hope others can develop good habits rather than only functional based.